# getting buffer overflow error using strcat

Tags: c++, char, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, strcat

New to C++, I was goofing around trying to get my head around complex systems like pointers and solving questions. I made this simple program which will concatenate char strings. But it always throws the same error: `L'buffer is too small &&0`.

Here is my code -

```
    const char* str = "larry";
    const char* yo{"is one of the stooges" };
    size_t buffer{ std::strlen(str) + std::strlen(yo) + 1 };
    std::cout << buffer;
    char* buff = new char[buffer];
    strcpy_s(buff, strlen(str), str);
    strcat(buff, yo);
    std::cout << *buff << std::endl;
    delete[] buff;
```

and here is my program output as requested:

```
27             // the size of buffer
```

the program then crashes.

Please point out whats wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Output should be `std::cout << buff`, without the `*` as you probably want to print the whole string, not just the first character.

Comment: thanks for pointing out typo, but that doesnt help with the `buffer overflow` error.Pls see if you can help me with that.Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. Can you tell which line triggers the error? Can you show the whole program output (including the buffer size), and the complete source code (minimal compilable example that causes the error), by editing your question?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 yes, the program crashes as soon as it executes the line with`strcpy_s(buff,strlen(str), str);`

Comment: Any special reason to use `strcpy_s` over the standard `strcpy`? It better not be MS's stupid safer function

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 yes unfortunately, i tried after disabling the safer function thing, the code works fine.But i still want to know why `strcpy_s` doesnt work.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Ive updated the question with the output.Thanks

Comment: [mcve] or it didn't happen.

Comment: @default-303 Ypou need to use  strcpy_s(buff, strlen(str) + 1, str);

Comment: Okay, firstly you need to understand that MS has neither implemented `strcpy`, nor the so called safer (and a fork to the original standard) `strcpy_s` following the standards. (In fact most of the implementations are non-standard)

Comment: @Swordfish indeed this is mre, its a part of a larger program with has objects.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 thanks for informing, i'll follow your advice

Comment: @VladfromMoscow and the award goes to Vladamir XD , thanks man

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard (K.3.7.1.3 The strcpy_s function)

> 2 Neither s1 nor s2 shall be a null pointer. s1max shall not be
> greater than RSIZE_MAX. s1max shall not equal zero. **s1max shall be
> greater than strnlen_s(s2, s1max)**. Copying shall not take place
> between objects that overlap.

That is you have to write

```
strcpy_s(buff, strlen(str) + 1, str);
```

Otherwise the terminating zero of the string pointed to by `str` will not be copied. In this case the next call

```
strcat(buff, yo);
```

invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `strcpy_s` is the size of the destination array, *including* the 0 byte. However, you pass in the size of the source string, *excluding* the 0 byte. `strcpy_s` attempts to copy the 0 byte, which it can't, as the destination array is supposedly (as indicated by the parameter) too small. Pass `buffer` (not a good name, btw) as the 2nd parameter to `strcpy_s` to indicate the destination size correctly.

Comment: Even better: use `strcpy`. You already know that the buffer is the correct size, so there is no need to check it again. +1.

Comment: Even more better would be `std::string`, but I think that's besides the point...

Comment: @Erlkoenig  i know, but i wanted to challenge my self.Thanks tho